# httpd.conf Webgate "LocationMatch" equivalent in IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, apache, iis, single-sign-on

Oracle's Webgate 10g for Single Sign-On, by default, checks for every single page on the site. This gives a negative performance hit for all pages on the site.

In order to limit the authentication service to a particular path within the site (say "/public"), in Apache one can edit the LocationMatch value in the httpd.conf file. The default value looks like this (all paths):

```
<LocationMatch "/*">
```

This value can be text edited to set a particular path instead, so that only pages within that path will be set:

```
<LocationMatch "/public/*">
```

**How can this same value be changed for an IIS Webgate 10g ISAPI filter?**

I have found articles, such as the following, that indicate that the path can be set in the Policy area of Oracle Access Manager (OAM) 11g (see step 10 in the following page, where by default the value is set to "/**" for IIS):

[Working with OIM: OAM 11gR2 - Protecting IIS Resources using 10g Webgate](http://ketanonoim.blogspot.com/2013/02/oam-11gr2-protecting-iis-resources-10g.html)

How can I make this change in IIS 7.5 without installing OAM?

If it's not possible, can I install OAM 11g (or 10g?) standalone, without the rest of the OIM packages? (I only need to change this one thing, so surely I don't need everything else?)

**Edit 1 Dec 2015: I have moved on to other projects, so am no longer able to test possible answers to this question. I have created an answer that I think would have solved the issue. Please consider all answers, and vote up any that work for your situation!**

Comment: Those are two very odd LocationMatch arguments, neither probably matches what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle now provides documents discussing how to set up OAM registration to specifically list protected and public resources. I think these would've solved my issue.

[Managing OAM 10g Webgates with OAM 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/admin.1111/e15478/webgate.htm#AIAAG4839) states that the `OAMRequest_short.xml` file can be used to specify protected/unprotected resources. However, their example doesn't seem to show how to do this.

[Registering Partners (Agents and Applications) Remotely](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/admin.1111/e15478/register.htm#AIAAG651) provides an example `OAMRequest_short.xml` file including protected and public resources. This page also includes a list of elements common to remote registration requests with descriptions and example usage.

Here is their example `OAMRequest_short.xml` file:

```
<OAMRegRequest>

    <serverAddress>http://sample.us.oracle.com:7001</serverAddress>
    <hostIdentifier>RREG_HostId11G</hostIdentifier>
    <agentName>Remote_Reg_OAM</agentName>
        <protectedResourcesList>
              <resource>/</resource>
              <resource>/.../*</resource>
         </protectedResourcesList>
         <publicResourcesList> 
              <resource>/public/index.html</resource>
         </publicResourcesList> 

</OAMRegRequest>
```

And, the descriptions for the protected and public resources list elements:

---

```
<protectedResourcesList>
```

> Specifies the resource URLs that you want the OAM Agent to protect with some authentication scheme. The resource URLs should be relative paths to the agentBaseUrl.

```
<protectedResourcesList>
    <resource>/</resource>
    <resource>/.../*</resource>
</protectedResourcesList>
```

---

```
<publicResourcesList>
```

> Specifies the resource URLs that you want to keep public (not protected by the OAM Agent). The resource URLs should be relative paths to the agentBaseUrl. For instance, you might want to specify the Home page or the Welcome page of your application

```
<publicResourcesList>
    <resource>/public/index.html</resource>
</publicResourcesList>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Create an Excluded policy for the resource for which you do not need OAM WebGate authentication and authorization.

Comment: Yes... but, how and where? I've now provided an answer as to how this can be done using the OAM registration process. Perhaps you can elaborate as to an alternative method.